# is there any way to hide a <form> input field but still making it usable?

Tags: html

what my issue is: is that I'm trying to make a simple website as a hobby project but for this i need to have a input field, so I used the one that  has but that was ugly. so a friend of mine made a SVG. now I'm trying to hide the  input field underneath the input field in the SVG

Comment: Form elements can be styled in all sorts of ways using CSS. I would suggest learning how to do that first.

Comment: You could style it to be hidden, you could use an `<input type="hidden">`, etc.  What did you try and what didn't work?

Comment: i tried using ```<input type="hidden">``` but then the input field would no longer work

Comment: You could try to set the fields opacity to 0 `<input style="opacity: 0;">` but it would probably be easier to take a swing at styling your input fields to look like the svg and then if your having troubles coming back here for advice on that.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add `style = "display: none;"` or `style = "visibility: collapse;"` which would make the input no longer visible to the user. The form will still grab the information from it and pass it to your back end. You can still use JavaScript on it as well as normal. As some comments pointed out, you can also use `<input type="hidden">` as another option.
`display: none;` has the page just not show the element at all, as if it were never on the page.
`visibility: collapse;` has the page render the page and then hide the field, keeping the formatting the same (i.e. if it were a cell in a table it would help set the width of a column and the width would be the same if it is or is not shown).
I recommend looking into both of these options more, as I find them both really useful! Here are links to learn more about
[Display](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) and [Visibility](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp)
At the end of the day, there are many different ways you can accomplish what you are wanting to do, just a matter of deciding what works best for you here.